# Compare Two Datatable that has same schema and N no of columns

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset, iequalitycomparer

I have two DataTables both has same no of columns and column names.Am in need of comparing both for the different rows.Which means even if one cell doesnt match the row should be plotted.I tried with

```
table1.Merge(table2);
DataTable modified = table2.GetChanges();
```

But this is returning null.

Where as

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> added = table1.AsEnumerable().Except(table2.AsEnumerable());
```

This is returning the table1 values alone even there are different values for a some cells in table1 compared to table2.

Can anyone help me for this comparison.Various sites i referred,the instruction said was to compare each column in a row but since i have N no of columns i cant go with that.I need a smarter way of comparison which would be efficient.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So you want to grab all rows that are not in both tables?

Comment: @mattm yes,I need to fetch all the mismatching rows and then find which cell or cells are the reason for the mismatch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> added = table1.AsEnumerable().Except(table2.AsEnumerable());
```

should be changed to

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> added = table1.AsEnumerable().Except(table2.AsEnumerable(),DataRowComparer.Default);
```

Because DataRows don't know how to compare themselves to eachother on their own. You can also provide your own equality delegate instead of DataRowComparer.Default if required.

Comment: This is exactly what i wanted.Thank yo ginkner.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using merge? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk68ew7b.aspx

```
Datatable1.Merge(datatable2);
DataTable DataTable3 = Datatable2.GetChanges();
```